# While making a function call in C, is the stack of OS used, and is the size of stack fixed?

Tags: c, function, memory, segmentation-fault, stack

Here's my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define ROW 10000
#define COLUMN 10000
void hello(int arr[ROW][COLUMN]){
    printf("hoho");
}
void main(){
    int arr[ROW][COLUMN];
    hello(arr);
}
```

Now, this gives me segmentation fault. My question is, that I understand that while making a function call, stack is used to keep all the variables passed to the function. So is this the stack of OS? i.e. does OS has a separate memory block designed specially for this?

Also, is the size of stack fixed?

What if I have to pass such great values to my functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS has a separate stack for all of its tasks. It would be terrible, if you could corrupt the OS memory so easily.
Depending on your compiler, you usually have a bout 1 MiB of stack memory. If you need to use such large amounts of memory, use `malloc` or `calloc` for allocating memory from the heap.

**Edit**

[This](http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0128776ff980970c-pi) is what Windows memory layout looks like.
[Here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/dude-wheres-my-4-gigabytes-of-ram.html) is the article on this.

Comment: 1MB? I dont think my array would take that much space?

Comment: Worse, but rather more accurate than @bash.d, `10^4*10^4==10^8`

Comment: @bash.d 10000*10000 is not 1 MILLION, way more than that.

Comment: @bash.d similary, does the OS provide separate heap for each process? What's the max limit on that?

Comment: @Kraken You are right... Failed at basic maths... You should get yourself acquaint with *virtual memory*, *paging* and stuff. For example on a 32-bit system, you will have 4 GiB of virtual memory the process can use. So, theoretically you can occupy 4 GiB of memory on the heap, BUT this will eventually kill your machine, as it will be busy paging over and over.

Comment: @bash.d I have one more doubt. Say instead of ` int arr[ROW][COLUMN];` i do `malloc for the same`. Now even if I do malloc, and after that I do hello(arr), then again my stack will be used for function call right? Or am I wrong in my understanding. 
When I 
I get that the memory I take by malloc is from heap, but does it go back to the same heap, while finction calls?

Comment: @bash.d orI guess, maybe the reference variable will be put on the stack, whereas the memory will be on the heap only? Is that so?

Also, when I do ` int arr[ROW][COLUMN];` then the memory I get from is stack?

Answer (score 2):

"It depends". C doesn't even specify that there is anything called "a stack" being used for either local variables or calls.

In practice, yes, it's the process' "real" operating system-created stack that is being used, since that generally has hardware support (most processors have the instructions to implement a stack very efficiently).

Typically, large arrays are best allocated "on the heap", i.e. with `malloc()`.

Comment: What is the max stack memory I can use using malloc()? Size of RAM?

Comment: @Kraken I don't think there is a guarantee of anything there, your operating system could for instance easily implement a per-process (or per-user) limit which would cause `malloc()` to fail. And that's *not* "stack memory", it's "heap" or "dynamic" memory.

Comment: Yeah, heap, sorry my bad. Thanks.

Comment: malloc() accepts size_t as parameter (implemented as unsigned int). So theoretically you can never exceed than 2^32 (4,294,967,296) bytes.

Comment: @Ali Not true on 64-bit systems.

Comment: @Ali: Furthermore `size_t` is not necessarily "implemented as unsigned int". The C standard requires it to be "an unsigned integer type". On the platform here, it is `long unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

if you are in linux

```
ulimit -a
```

this is the command to see stack size along with other options

```
 ulimit -s unlimited
```

will set the stack size to unlimited size

in my machine it was

**stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192**

where it produced a seg fault and on altering the stack size to unlmited it did work fine

may be

```
man -a ulimit
```

is the option to resolve this in program logic

P.S - this is specific to linux environment

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not. Applications work at user mode, and has its own memory space. For modern OS, each application works at its own memory space, one wouldn't write/read to another's memory (unless using shared memory).
When you put too much values, you get stack-over-flow.